# github action AND OR

Tags: github, github-actions

been trying to test this workflow but seems  doesn't  work and not getting the expected result

```
name: Deploy  App
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      app_name:
        description: 'app'
        required: true
        default: 'app1'
        type: choice
        options:
        - app1
        - app2
      todo:
        description: 'deploy or destroy
        required: true
        default: 'deploy'
        type: choice
        options:
        - deploy
        - destroy
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -ileo pipefail {0}  # for bash usage

jobs:
  check-plan:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, my-runner]
    outputs: 
      runner: ${{ steps.set_runner.outputs.runner }}   
    steps:
      - name: Env Inputs
        if: github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
        run: |
          echo "todo=${{inputs.todo}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV         
          echo "app=${{inputs.app}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
 
      - name: Check and Test
        if: ${{ (env.todo == 'deploy') && (env.app == 'app1') || (env.app == 'app2)' }}  
        run: |
          echo "{{ env.todo}} is {{ env.app}}"
```

Error I'm getting

```
Run echo "{{ env.todo }} is {{ env.app }}"
echo "{{ env.todo }} the {{ env.todo }}"
shell: /usr/bin/bash -ileo pipefail {0}
env:
app: app1
todo: deploy
bash: cannot set terminal process group (13): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
{{ env.todo }} the {{ env.app }}
```

I would like to try this = if todo is deploy and  app is app1 or app2 then send an echo output

Comment: Redundant single quote in `if` at the end. Missing $ for `${{...}}` in `echo`. Fix these issues. Also, lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/.

Comment: sorry it should not have that quote, I modified my question and still has same issue

Comment: Right. The indentation of `run` section is off. Please include the rest of your workflow. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: alright, I included all the gh workflow, updated my post

Comment: You're using self-hosted runners. What kind of runners are these? Have you tested this with `ubuntu-latest` runner? Also, looks like `env.app` and `env.todo` should be `inputs.app` and `inputs.todo` as they're coming from the `workflow_dispatch` event's inputs.

Comment: @Azeem - yes the runners are tested, I forgot to include the "Env Inputs" part of the workflow (sorry again). I have updated my post and added it.

Comment: The `outputs` is also redundant. Can you please create a working MCVE as suggested above? Should be reproducible in GHA hosted runner as well. It could be that the issue you're showing is only specific to your self hosted runners. You have two runners in your workflow, which one is it where this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this myself, I just added the missing $